# multiple add/remove rows on one page

Tags: jquery

There are variations on this theme on here already, but nothing that corresponds completely. Yet, this question must come up a lot.

I need to have multiple add/remove table rows on a single page. I have researched this a lot online, and there are many examples that work well for a single table, but once you add a second table, everything goes crazy. It should be a simple matter of relying on an `ID` for each table, but I have not been able to accomplish this, and I really don't want to repeat big chunks of jquery code on my page.

Here is the jquery, which is largely taken from an online demo. I know that I am repeating the `ID` for my table, so I post this code intentionally leaving this error.

```js
jQuery(document).delegate('a.add-record', 'click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();    
   var content = jQuery('#sample_table tr'),
   size = jQuery('#tbl_posts >tbody >tr').length + 1,
   element = null,    
   element = content.clone();
   element.attr('id', 'rec-'+size);
   element.find('.delete-record').attr('data-id', size);
   element.appendTo('#tbl_posts_body');
  });
   
  jQuery(document).delegate('a.delete-record', 'click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();    
   var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
   var targetDiv = jQuery(this).attr('targetDiv');
   jQuery('#rec-' + id).remove();

   return true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!----------START TABLE 1 HERE---------->
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table table-bordered third" id="tbl_posts">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <div class="well clearfix">
       <td colspan="4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><div class="button" width="100%">CLICK TO ADD A ROW</div></a>
    </td>
   </div>
         </tr>
         </thead>
              <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
                <TR id="rec-1">
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="something[]">
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   </form>
  
 <!----------TABLE 1 NEW ROWS---------->
 <div style="display:none;">
     <table id="sample_table">
   <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
      <tr id="">
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="something[]"></input>
   </TD>

   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
   </TD>   
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
   </TD>
   <TD>
   <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
   </td>
   </TR>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
 <!----------END TABLE 1 HERE---------->
 <BR><HR><BR>
 <!----------START TABLE 2 HERE---------->
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table table-bordered third" id="tbl_posts">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <div class="well clearfix">
       <td colspan="4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><div class="button" width="100%">CLICK TO ADD A ROW</div></a>
    </td>
   </div>
         </tr>
         </thead>
              <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
                <TR id="rec-1">
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="something[]">
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   </form>
  
 <!----------TABLE 2 NEW ROWS---------->
 <div style="display:none;">
     <table id="sample_table">
   <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
      <tr id="">
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="something[]"></input>
   </TD>

   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]"></input>
   </TD>   
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]"></input>
   </TD>
   <TD>
   <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
   </td>
   </TR>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
 <!----------END TABLE 2 HERE---------->
```

Comment: Please share a **not** working example.

Comment: @TimSch Okay, done!

Comment: You need to  add/remove multiple rows in two table right?

Comment: That's right, and in any other tables on the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will work for as many tables as you want.

As requested, I have created demo rows in each of the tables that are hidden using the class `.demo-row`. By clicking `.add-record` an event is fired which searches the table which it is embedded in the for the `.first()` row with the class `.demo-row` before copying it into a variable and and removing the `.demo-row` class (so that it will be shown). It then `.appends` this to the relevant table.

`.delete-record` operates similarly, using `.closest(tr)` to find the row it is embedded within and deleting it via `.remove()`. You need to use `$(document).on("click",...` in order to apply the click event to dynamic creating elements.

```js
$(".add-record").click( function() {

  row = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").first().find("tr.demo-row").first().clone().removeClass("demo-row");
  
  $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").first().append( row );

});


$(document).on("click", "a.delete-record" , function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```css
tr.demo-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table table-bordered third" id="tbl_posts">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <div class="well clearfix">
       <td colspan="4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><div class="button" width="100%">CLICK TO ADD A ROW</div></a>
    </td>
   </div>
         </tr>
         </thead>
              <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
              
              
              <TR class="demo-row">
              <TD>
              I like pears.
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
              
              
                <TR id="rec-1">
              <TD>
              I like pears.
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   </form>
    
    
    
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table table-bordered third" id="tbl_posts">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <div class="well clearfix">
       <td colspan="4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record" data-added="0"><div class="button" width="100%">CLICK TO ADD A ROW</div></a>
    </td>
   </div>
         </tr>
         </thead>
              <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
              
              <TR class="demo-row">
              <TD>
              I like apples.
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
              
                <TR id="rec-1">
              <TD>
              I like apples.
              </TD>

              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]">
              </TD>   
              <TD>
              <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]">
              </TD>
                    <TD>
              <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
              </TD>
              </TR>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   </form>
  
  
 <!----------NEW ROWS---------->
 <div style="display:none;">
     <table id="sample_table">
   <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">
      <tr id="">
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="something[]"></input>
   </TD>

   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelse[]"></input>
   </TD>   
   <TD>
   <input type="text" name="somethingelseagain[]"></input>
   </TD>
   <TD>
   <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">REMOVE</a>
   </td>
   </TR>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: The `.delete-record` function seems to be unreliable in this example... when I try it, it removes rows only some of the time.

Comment: Yep! Sorry, you can't use `.click()` as this only adds events to elements that exist when the page finishes loading (that's why it is working for the two rows that already exist in the demo). I've updated the answer so that it recognises clicks on dynamically created rows as well.

Comment: This is progressing very nicely! But another constraint is that the second (and any subsequent) table may not have identical contents.... Sorry, I neglected to mention that in my original post.

Comment: I've added that functionality

Comment: Fantastic! This is really useful info. I hope that others can make use of it to.